# Not able to run nmake on windows, link given on the body

Tags: windows, cmake, nmake

I am trying to build the source of CURA; (Link: https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/wiki/Running-Cura-from-Source-on-Windows). I followed the instructions but got error as below:

```
PS D:\work\cura-build-environment-master\build> nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1064: MAKEFILE not found and no target specified
Stop.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may not have followed **all** of the instructions, such as [this one](https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/wiki/Running-Cura-from-Source-on-Windows#microsoft-visual-studio-2019) in the **Microsoft Visual Studio 2019** section:

> 4. When building files (using cmake or nmake) in the steps below ***be sure to use the 'VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt'***. This ensures that the Visual Studio 2015 build tools are used.

Comment: Hi, As per your suggestion I have tried the way mentioned in step 4 and I got the same error